# Why does elasticbeanstalk fails a deploy but shows latest application version?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elasticbenastalk (eb) web node.js application in a working environment.

I'm using a well built zip file in order to deploy.

The thing is that after deploying, eb dashboard displays a green status and the correct version number for the application (the one I want to deploy). This should be the expected result (api-0.0.22 is the latest available version).

[image: Supposed deployed version]

However, in a randomly manner, the deploy software doesn't change (I have a version file in order to confirm which is the effective deployed version). When I detect this, I also can see a timeout in the events' log that confirms the non-deployment.

[image: EB events' log]

I've gone through the available logs and I couldn't find any attempts to download the software from S3 nor installing it. I mean that is there not only a lack of errors but also a lack of proof of the deployment. It looks as if 'it never happened'.

I'm also using one ebextension for logging (logging.config):

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/bundlelogs.d/01-appname.conf":
    content: |
      /var/app/current/log/error.log

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/01-appname.conf":
    content: |
      /var/app/current/log/error.log
```

Note: /var/app/current/log exists in the application file tree

I've been making lots of tests and one of them gave me a little light over the dark: if I terminate the eb related instance that timeouts, eb launches another one with the correct (and expected) application version.

I don't know if this issue could be code related (that is why I'm using stack overflow) or eb setup or deployment method.

Any suggestions/ideas will be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any ebextensions? Have you tried increasing the timeout as the error states?

Comment: Have you looked at the full logs? `eb logs --all`

Comment: Yes, I have only one ebextension (logging.config) with is working as expected. I've also increased the timeout (double) with the same result

Comment: About the logs, I've ssh'ed into the ec2 instance instead of using eb logs --all (however the result is the same). No errors nor trace of the deployment

Comment: As per your information, you have already made a clear inspection of the log files but I would suggest you to again run grep (with -nR) on /var/log/ for words such as _ERROR_, _failed with error code_ and _Return code_. Sometimes, its easy to miss things as we tend to overlook while debugging the issues. What's the instance type you're using? It could be the limited resource if you are using instances with less RAM. Have you tried cloning the environment and checking the same thing on the cloned environment?

Comment: Also, is it possible to post logging.config by replacing sensitive information if any (as it could work properly on its own but affect later part of executions)

Comment: I've edited the question to add the ebextension. No errors in log files. The instance type is micro and I tried also with small. This app is at development stage so there are no much resources being used. However I'll try (on Monday) with a way bigger instance  to discard resource issue.

Comment: Well, I could explain to you why the app-version is showing the latest, but Im still not sure why the deploy is timeing out with no errors. I would raise this with support.

Comment: I'm probably raising to support after checking out if it has something to do with the instance resources. I'd be pleased to hear about the last version being showed :)